# Show specific month when zoomed on a quarterly chart using highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm looking for a way to reveal the months between specific quarters on an areaspline chart.

Here's the view when zoomed out:

[image: Highcharts]
Here it is zoomed in:

[image]

What I'd like to do is show the months between Jan '14 and Apr '14 (and the rest as well) whenever a user is zoomed into the chart.

Points of interest:

`xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    tickInterval: 3 * 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000
}`

`series: [{
      name: 'X',
      data: [
        [Date.UTC(2014,0,1), randomNumber()],
        [Date.UTC(2014,1,1), randomNumber()],
        [Date.UTC(2014,2,1), randomNumber()],
        [Date.UTC(2014,3,1), randomNumber()],
        [Date.UTC(2014,4,1), randomNumber()],
        [Date.UTC(2014,5,1), randomNumber()],
        [Date.UTC(2014,6,1), randomNumber()],
        [Date.UTC(2014,7,1), randomNumber()],
        [Date.UTC(2014,8,1), randomNumber()],
        [Date.UTC(2014,9,1), randomNumber()],
        [Date.UTC(2014,10,1), randomNumber()],
        [Date.UTC(2014,11,1), randomNumber()],
        [Date.UTC(2014,12,1), randomNumber()]
      ]
    }]`

Here's a codepen of what I got so far:
http://codepen.io/DavidVII/pen/cjdLf?editors=001

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after reading their docs I found `tickInterval` and `afterSetExtream` to be what I needed to go from a quarterly view to a monthly view once I'm zoomed in.

Here's a code example:

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  tickInterval: 3 * 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
  events: {
    afterSetExtremes: function(event){
      if (event.max < this.getExtremes().dataMax || event.min > this.getExtremes().dataMin) {
        this.update({
          tickInterval: 1 * 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000
        });
      } else {
        this.update({
          tickInterval: 3 * 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

Here's a really simple working example:
http://codepen.io/DavidVII/full/cjdLf/

And here's the code in it's entirety if you are interested:
http://codepen.io/DavidVII/pen/cjdLf/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner) which allows to prepare function for dynamic ticks. In the body of funcion, you can compare dataMin/dataMax with min/max and you will know if chart is zoomed or not.

Comment: Any way you could provide an example?